# How to read json array from local json file using javascript in global.asa file?

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic, jscript

I am using db connection to get data in global.asa.
Now, I want to get data from local json file instead of db connection.

I know it is available to use both of VBscript and javascript in global.asa.
I'd like to use javascript to get json array from local json file.
After getting json array, I need to set several variables of json to session variable.

This is my original global.asa file.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript RUNAT=Server>
Sub Session_OnStart
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
....

myConnection = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; PORT=3306; DATABASE=FirstAuto_; USER=xxxx; PASSWORD='xyz'; OPTION=0;"


set cnn = server.createObject("ADODB.connection")
cnn.ConnectionString = GloConnectionString
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cnn.open myConnection
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

if instr(Request.ServerVariables("server_name"),"www.") Then
request_url =  Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
Else
request_url = "https://www." &   replace(Request.ServerVariables("server_name"),"mobile.","")
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.AddHeader "Location", request_url
'Destroys the Session. So that future calls will retrigger this code. 
Session.Abandon 
'Sends buffered output immediately. 
Response.Flush 
'Stops processing the .asp file and returns the current result. 
Response.End 
response.redirect "https://www." & Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
End If


mySQL = "SELECT websites.id AS website_id, websites.city as Market, websites.state, websites.state_abrev,"&_
        " websites.county, websites.company, websites.google_tag, websites.latitude,"&_
        " websites.longitude, websites.zoom, websites.dbUserName, "&_
        " websites.hp_slider,  websites.finance, websites.warranty, websites.theme, websites.autonet_url,"&_
        " websites.autonet_key,  websites.ppc, websites.website_url, websites.general_auto,"&_
        " websites.estimates, websites.type, websites.shareThis, websites.owner_id "&_
        " FROM websites where websites.website_url = 'http://" & request_url & "'"  

set rs=cnn.execute(mySQL)
session("url") = replace(rs("website_url"),"http:","https:")
session("website") = cInt(rs("website_id"))
session("hp_slider") = cInt(rs("hp_slider"))

rs.close
set rs = nothing
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub


</SCRIPT>
```

I want to set session values like url, website, hp_slider with json array from local json file.

Comment: One thing you will have to do is find (or write) a JSON parser as JScript does not have one built in.  There are a few already out there, you will have to try them and decide which you like.  You should also experiment with calling JScript from VBScript which is pretty straight forward.

Comment: P.S.  If you use a VBScript JSON parser you don't even need to cross the JScript boundry.

Comment: I use this in classic ASP with js and it works fine: http://www.JSON.org/json2.js

Comment: Thanks @PeterVC.

Answer (score 0):

> I know it is available to use both of VBscript and javascript in
>   global.asa

Yep.  Since you are considering parsing JSON, I might recommend this approach to minimize your coding efforts.  Note: On the down-side, this approach does have a higher resource overhead, since both JScript and VBScript engines are loaded in-memory.

For this example, just open and read the contents of the JSON file, then eval() the JSON contents into a local JScript variable, then assign the value(s) to Session variables:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JScript RUNAT=Server>
var t = null;
with (new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")) {
    with (OpenTextFile("my.json", 1)) {
        t = ReadAll();
        Close();
    }
}

var myJson = null;
eval("myJson = " + t);
Session("myjson_url") = myJson.url;
Session("myjson_website") = myJson.website;
Session("myjson_hp_slider") = myJson.hp_slider;
</SCRIPT>
```

For the example above, I used this my.json file:

```
{"url": "http://www.somewhere.com/path/page.htm", "website": "somewhere.com", "hp_slider": 50}
```

It could have easily just been a JSON array.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks @leeharvey1